# Why am I getting an error "print_unicode: line 9: printf: missing unicode digit for \u Unicode 0187" with this script

Tags: bash, shell-script, unicode, echo, printf

I have written them following shell script to view what the Unicode characters look like on my terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

X=0

while [ $X -lt 65536 ]; do
    HEX=`bc <<< "obase=16; $X"`
    HEX="0x${HEX}"
    UCODENAME=`printf "%0*x\n" 4 $HEX`
    UCODECHAR=`printf "\u%0*x\n" 4 $HEX`
    echo -e "Unicode ${UCODENAME} = ${UCODECHAR}"
    X=$((X + 1))
done
```

When I run the script I receive the following output:

```
print_unicode: line 9: printf: missing unicode digit for \u
Unicode 0188 = ƈ
```

The second line is exactly what I am looking for.

I did try using strictly `printf` in an attempt to eliminate the error.

```
#!/bin/bash

X=0

while [ $X -lt 65536 ]; do
    HEX=`bc <<< "obase=16; $X"`
    HEX="0x${HEX}"
    printf 'Unicode %0*x = \u%0*x\n' 4 $HEX 4 $HEX
    X=$((X + 1))
done
```

I get the following output:

```
print_unicode: line 8: printf: missing unicode digit for \u
Unicode 037f = \u037f
```

The second line is not what I am looking for, and I still get the same error message.

How do I fix this error?

Bonus: What is a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the mistake you get is that:
The builtin printf understand the `\U` (or `\u`) only when it is followed by an actual number:

```
$ printf '\U0021'
!
```

To make it to create the number and also convert it, a two step printf is needed (a double \ is needed to pass thru the double quote):

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%04X' 33)"
!
```

As you want it:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\u%0*X' 4 33)"
!
```

This also work:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%0*X' 8 33)"
!
```

There is no need to use bc to tell bash of hexadecimal numbers.
bash could understand this perfectly well:

```
$ a=$(( 0xdef )); echo $(( a + 1 ))
3568
```

And to get the hexadecimal value of a number `printf` is good enough:

```
$ printf '0x%06x' 3568
0x000df0
```

---

The loop could be simplified to:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp=$((0x020))     len=6

for (( cp=32; cp<$((0x010000)); cp++)); do    
    Ucode="$(printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%0*X' "$len" "$cp")")"
    printf 'Unicode U%0*x = %s\n' 4 "$cp" "$Ucode"
done
```

**BEWARE** From 0x20 to 0x010000 there are a lot of lines (~ 64k lines).

I increased the len to 6 as UNICODE could have code points up to 10FFFF.

Of course, Ucode is fully defined by this:

```
Ucode="$(printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%0*X' $len "$cp")")"
```

Note that code points (`cp`) below dec=32 or HEX=0x20 are control characters.

Even if the code works for such codepoints I do **not** recommend you to play with them.

**EXCEPT** for UNICODE U0000 because the value is being assigned to a variable.

This prints `\0`

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%0*X' "6" "0")"
```

Confirm with xxd:

```
$ printf '%b' "$(printf '\\U%0*X' "6" "0")" | xxd
0000000: 00
```

**CAVEAT**: Bash below 4.3 fail to correctly encode values between U0080 and U00FF in utf-8. Please use version 4.3 or 4.4 .

Comment: `"\\u"` still gives an error `printf: missing unicode digit for \u`, i found that `"\\\u"` is works better an outputs `\u` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I kept experimenting a found a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

X=0

while [ $X -lt 65536 ]; do
    HEX=`bc <<< "obase=16; $X"`
    HEX="0x${HEX}"
    UCODE=`printf "%0*x\n" 4 $HEX`
    printf "Unicode ${UCODE} = \u${UCODE}\n"
    X=$((X + 1))
done
```

I got the idea to try printf this way from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux

I'm still open to seeing more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a different way (since bash appears to ignore escaped backslashes around the `u` in `"\u"`):

```
#!/bin/bash

X=0

while [ $X -lt 65536 ]; do
    HEX=$(bc <<< "obase=16; $X")
    HEX="0x${HEX}"
    UCODENAME=$(printf "%0*x\n" 4 $HEX)
    UCODECHAR="\\u$(printf "%0*x" 4 $HEX)"
    echo -e "Unicode ${UCODENAME} = ${UCODECHAR}"
    X=$((X + 1))
done
```

though of course, the script is still bash-specific.  A few other comments:

- most people would suggest using `$(` and `)` rather than back-tics.
- bash's `printf` can print Unicode directly (no need for the echo).
- the extra `printf` for `UCODECHAR` is redundant

Eliminating the redundancy:

```
#!/bin/bash

X=0

while [ $X -lt 65536 ]; do
    HEX=$(bc <<< "obase=16; $X")
    HEX="0x${HEX}"
    UCODENAME=$(printf "%0*x\n" 4 $HEX)
    UCODECHAR="\\u${UCODENAME}"
    echo -e "Unicode ${UCODENAME} = ${UCODECHAR}"
    X=$((X + 1))
done
```

Comment: Please read my answer, bash does not ignore backslash. But to get it working correctly it may be tricky sometimes.